# How to change default URL of jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have installed jupyterhub on amazon linux and I have changed my server ip and port in config file. However I wanted to change the default URL that is shown in browser. I have tried changing the `c.JupyterHub.default_url` in config file but that is only given as an extension to my ip and port (`http://x.x.x.x:8080/hub/myjupyter`)and that didn't help.

Currently my hub starts with `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080`URL but I want to change it to something like `http://myjupyter.abc.com`.

`abc.com` could be my organization website. In this case does this require SSL key and certificate? Or can I configure the URL without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of computers that will be accessing the JupyterHub installation? You also didn't mention which OS you are using on the clients accessing the server.

One way is to map the private ip to your domain name of choice in the /etc/hosts file (windows has it at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`), but you'd need to do this on every client computer.

If your organization has a private DNS server on the network, you can configure the mapping there as well. Then you wouldn't have to do it on each client manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am working amazon linux. Need to check the process as suggested.

Comment: Is your amazon instance where jupyterhub is installed publicly accessible? How are the client computers accessing it?

If it's publicly accessible, then you should be able to map the ip address of the ec2 instance to a domain name you own (needs to be registered via a provider like GoDaddy, Namesilo etc) via amazon Route53 settings.

Comment: Clients will be accessing through a different IP which I have already changed in config file. Does the suggested process require SSL to be enabled?

Comment: No you don't have to enable SSL, it should work with or without it since it's mapping an IP address to a domain name.